# Background image will not show up in CSS using the Brackets editor

Tags: html, css

Im trying to create my first web project using Brackets and cannot get the background image to show up.

My css code is

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  color: #555;
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.row {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  background-image: url(../img/hero.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/grid.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Omnifood</title>

</head>

<body>
  <header>

    <div class="hero-text-box">
      <h1>Goodbye junk food. Hello super healthy meals.</h1>
      <a href="#">I'm hungry!</a>
      <a href="#">Show me more</a>

    </div>

  </header>

</body>




</html>
```

I've been following a course online and have typed all the code in identically. I don't know why my background image wont appear. I dont think its a problem with the file tree as when I click on the url(../img/hero.jpg) Brackets shows me that it recognizes the image. Any help would by greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You don't need the ".." in front of "img"

Comment: URL for background-image should be inside quotation marks

Comment: @SamVarghese It's odd, but you don't need the quotes unless you have a space in your path.

Comment: I've removed the .. and tried "" and ''. Neither has made my background-image appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two things going on here that will get it working again:

1. Your css declaration for `header` is referencing a class but I think you want it to reference a tag `header`.
2. Will want to make sure the url path is relative and surrounded by quotes. The example below references one that is hosted online. The snippet you supplied didn't have the path inside quotes: `'../url/destination'`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  color: #555;
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.row {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background-image: url('https://global-uploads.webflow.com/5ef5480befd392489dacf544/5f9f5e5943de7e69a1339242_5f44a7398c0cdf460857e744_img-image-p-1080.jpeg');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/grid.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Omnifood</title>

</head>

<body>
  <header>

    <div class="hero-text-box">
      <h1>Goodbye junk food. Hello super healthy meals.</h1>
      <a href="#">I'm hungry!</a>
      <a href="#">Show me more</a>
    </div>

  </header>

</body>




</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't even notice the . before header until you pointed it out. That was the probelm.

Answer (score 1):

You are targeting the class .header instead of the tag header.

```html
header {   /* Change from .header to header */
  background-image: url("../img/hero.jpg"); /* Add Quotes */
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently CSS is not recognizing the file path. I suggest you describe it more extensively to resolve this error: "C:\Users\Name\img\hero.jpg"